# how to perform multiple ajax queries within an ajax block

Tags: php, jquery, sql, ajax

am working on a project in which i use ajax, jquery, php and sql to manipulate data.

```
function fetchComments(commentOnId, commentOn){
if(!isNaN(commentOnId) && commentOnId >=0){
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        url: 'get_comments.php',
        data: 'commentOnId='+commentOnId+'&commentOn=blogArticle',
        success: function(data){},
        error: function(){
        }
    }); 
}
}
```

the above function uses the 'commentOnId & commentOn' passed to it to fetch all comment on that that particular blog id in json format.
the result/rows in my comment table are as follows.
id
commentOnId
commentOn
commentText
authorId
created

what i want to do is get the values of these rows and in this same function run another ajax query which i will pass the authorId to a php file that returns an authors's full name from a table called authorDetails,
and also use the id value to run another ajax query to return all replies on this comment id or null if there is no reply. and finally update a html div '' with the result.

please, i will appreciate your quick comprehensive assistance. thank you.

Comment: why not make another ajax request from the `success: function(data){//run ajax query from here}` ?

Comment: Why not get the data you need on the serverside and send it all in one reqeuest ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQL joins to get all your needed data in one request if you don't want other details on user iterative basis.

Comment: Thanks, but please how do I  select all from comment table and select fName, lName from authorDetails table where authorDetail.id=comment.authorId get

Comment: Refer: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would fetch everything in a single Ajax call rather than perform another Ajax call.

If you want multiple Ajax calls, you can do the following.

```
    function fetchComments(commentOnId, commentOn){
        if(!isNaN(commentOnId) && commentOnId >=0){
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: "json",
                url: 'get_comments.php',
                data: 'commentOnId='+commentOnId+'&commentOn=blogArticle',
                success: function(data){
                    $.ajax({
                        type :'post',
                        url : 'get_auth_details.php',
                        data : 'authorId=' + data.authorId,
                        success : function(data) {
                            Update div logic goes here
                        }
                    }
               },
               error: function(){
               }
           }); 
       }
   }
```

Comment: Thanks. Please how do I achieve this task in a single ajax call.?